# Ramda - how to use multiple functions on the same data structure

Tags: ramda.js

I am trying to use multiple ramda functions on this example:

```
const data = {
  "tableItems": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "1",
      "startingPoint": true,
      "pageNumber": 15,
      "nodes": [
        100,
        200
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "2",
      "startingPoint": true,
      "pageNumber": 14,
      "nodes": [
        300,
        400
      ]
    }
  ],
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": 100,
      "tableItemId": 1,
      "content": "test"
    },
    {
      "id": 200,
      "tableItemId": 1,
      "content": "test"
    },
    {
      "id": 300,
      "tableItemId": 2,
      "content": "test"
    },
    {
      "id": 400,
      "tableItemId": 2,
      "content": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to create new JSON which should look like this where `nodes` array should be filled with another ramda function:

```
const newJSON = [
  {
    "id": "chapter-1",
    "name": "2",
    "nodes": []
  },
  {
    "id": "chapter-2",
    "name": "1",
    "nodes": []
  }
]
```

I started with:

```
let chapters = [];
let chapter;

const getChapters = R.pipe(
  R.path(['tableItems']),
  R.sortBy(R.prop('pageNumber')),
  R.map((tableItem) => {
    if(tableItem.startingPoint) {
      chapter = {
        id: `chapter-${chapters.length+1}`,
        name: tableItem.name,
        nodes: []
      }
      chapters.push(chapter);
    }
    return tableItem
  })
)
```

But how to combine `getNodes` which needs access to the whole scope of `data`?

I tried `pipe` but something is not working.

Example:

```
const getNodes = R.pipe(
  R.path(['nodes']),
  R.map((node) => {
    console.log(node)
  })
)

R.pipe(
  getChapters,
  getNodes
)(data)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could write something like this, using Ramda:

```js
const {pipe, sortBy, prop, filter, map, applySpec, identity, propEq, find, __, addIndex, assoc} = R

const transform = ({tableItems, nodes}) => pipe (
  filter (prop ('startingPoint')),
  sortBy (prop ('pageNumber')),
  map (applySpec ({
    name: prop('name'),
    nodes: pipe (prop('nodes'), map (pipe (propEq ('id'), find (__, nodes))), filter (Boolean))
  })),
  addIndex (map) ((o, i) => assoc ('id', `chapter-${i + 1}`, o))
) (tableItems)


const data = {tableItems: [{id: 1, name: "1", startingPoint: true, pageNumber: 15, nodes: [100, 200]}, {id: 2, name: "2", startingPoint: true, pageNumber: 14, nodes: [300, 400]}], nodes: [{id: 100, tableItemId: 1, content: "test"}, {id: 200, tableItemId: 1, content: "test"}, {id: 300, tableItemId: 2, content: "test"}, {id: 400, tableItemId: 2, content: "test"}]}

console .log (transform (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

First we filter the `tableItems` to include only those with `startingPoint` of `true`,  then we sort the result by `pageNumber`.  Then for each, we create `name` and `nodes` elements, based on the original data and on a function that maps the node values to the element in the initial `nodes` property.  Finally, for each one, we add the `chapter-#` `id` element using `addIndex (map)`.

This works, and is not horrible.  It would take a fair bit of work to make this entirely point-free, I believe.  And I don't find it worthwhile... especially because this Ramda version doesn't add anything to a simpler vanilla implementation:

```js
const transform = ({tableItems, nodes}) =>
  tableItems 
    .filter (x => x .startingPoint)
    .sort (({pageNumber: a}, {pageNumber: b}) => a - b)
    .map (({name, nodes: ns}, i) => ({
      id: `chapter-${i + 1}`,
      name,
      nodes: ns .map (n => nodes .find (node => node .id == n)) .filter (Boolean)
    }))

const data = {tableItems: [{id: 1, name: "1", startingPoint: true, pageNumber: 15, nodes: [100, 200]}, {id: 2, name: "2", startingPoint: true, pageNumber: 14, nodes: [300, 400]}], nodes: [{id: 100, tableItemId: 1, content: "test"}, {id: 200, tableItemId: 1, content: "test"}, {id: 300, tableItemId: 2, content: "test"}, {id: 400, tableItemId: 2, content: "test"}]}

console .log (transform (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This works similarly to the above except that it assigns the `id` at the same time as `name` and `nodes`.

I'm a founder of Ramda and remain a big fan.  But it doesn't always add anything to vanilla modern JS.

Comment: As always excellent answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [curried function](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#curryN). Because the pipe will always pipe the result of the previous function call into the next function. You can use `R.tap` if you want to step over.

However, I guess you want to have the `data` object and the output of the previous function call both in your `getNodes` function. In that case you can use a curried function, where you pass the response of the previous function as last parameter.

```
const getNodes = R.curryN(2, function(data, tableItemList){
  console.log(tableItemList) // result of previous function call

  return R.pipe(
     R.path(['nodes']),
     R.map((node) => {
       console.log('node:', node);
    })
  )(data)
})
```

And use it like:

```
R.pipe(
 getChapters,
  getNodes(data)
)(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would split the solution into two steps:

1. Prepare the `tableItems` and `nodes` to the required end state using `R.evolve` - filter, sort, and then use `R.toPairs` the `tableItems` to get an array that includes the index and the object. Group the `nodes` by `id` so you can pick the relevant nodes by `id` in the combine step.
2. Combine both properties to create the end result by mapping the new `tableItems`, and using `R.applySpec` to create the properties.

```js
const {pipe, evolve, filter, prop, sortBy, toPairs, groupBy, map, applySpec, path, flip, pick} = R

const transform = pipe(
  evolve({ // prepare
    tableItems: pipe(
      filter(prop('startingPoint')),
      sortBy(prop('pageNumber')),
      toPairs
    ),
    nodes: groupBy(prop('id'))
  }),
  ({ tableItems, nodes }) => // combine
    map(applySpec({
      id: ([i]) => `chapter-${+i + 1}`,
      name: path([1, 'name']),
      nodes: pipe(path([1, 'nodes']), flip(pick)(nodes)),
    }))(tableItems)
)

const data = {tableItems: [{id: 1, name: "1", startingPoint: true, pageNumber: 15, nodes: [100, 200]}, {id: 2, name: "2", startingPoint: true, pageNumber: 14, nodes: [300, 400]}], nodes: [{id: 100, tableItemId: 1, content: "test"}, {id: 200, tableItemId: 1, content: "test"}, {id: 300, tableItemId: 2, content: "test"}, {id: 400, tableItemId: 2, content: "test"}]}

console.log(transform(data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```